# How do I make Filemaker "Insert from URL" work in Webdirect

Tags: filemaker

Filemaker Pro 14.0 with Google Chrome and Safari both did not seem to work with WebDirect. The code concerned is:

[image: filemaker screenshot]

So this works fine in filemaker client and I get a http request logged on my http server and a proper response is received. Webdirect somehow does not like it and I get no response, nor do I get a hit on my http server. What is even strange is that, it does not even show the current record from the database (the first record, which was selected on line 3).

My best guess is I am doing something which is not supported by WebDirect but fail to understand what exactly.

Basically what I am trying to do, is make a http request and retrieve the response text into a FileMaker variable. I am doing this by saving the response in a column and then retrieving the value of the column in a variable.

PS: Can someone also point me out how I can copy text from the scripting window?

Comment: Regarding the copying of script text, the only way I know to do so is to use the MBS plugin, http://www.monkeybreadsoftware.de/filemaker/. You can install the demo file and even without purchase it supports that feature. Additional features are available with purchase.

Comment: I did install the plugin for MBS, however am facing other issues with that! Maybe that is best left for another stackoverflow question. Basically, even with that I am unable to copy the text to clipboard.

Comment: What do you want to do with the copied text?? The BaseElements plugin which is free will get clipboard data, so will a programme like ClipManager, or you can export a DDR and get the steps from FMPerception..

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid there's much that seems wrong with the script. Perhaps you mistyped it, not having the ability to copy and paste the script?

- `Show Custom Dialog` can't directly set the value of a variable. You need to use the input fields to set the value of a field, usually a global field, and you can then use that directly or you can move that value to a variable.
- You don't seem to be setting the `http_wrapper_response::response` field to any value. The way you have that written, it will actually clear any value it may have.
- The third line doesn't set the current record, it sets the text selection to the contents of that field, which you're clearing in the line above.

Comment: I have actually set the variable on an earlier line. I did not include it, since the URL was confidential. So that was your first point.
The second point is correct, I want to over-write the variable. Regarding the third issue, I am aware it sets the selection to the first field, I want the field to be overwritten.